# Git from a central repository

Tags: git, svn, netbeans, ssh, versioning

We have recently been forced to use versioning due to projects seem to be bigger and bigger.

I'm wondering how to use git from two or more workstations connected to projects as a remote project accessed over ssh.

We are using netbeans and the projects are opened as remote projects and every save is synced and the files are updated on the server (ssh).

How is this done in GIT or is there a better way of using GIT for working on same project from different locations and users?

Regards

Comment: https://www.atlassian.com/git/

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I've read the documentation, but I can not see anywhere how to  use git the way we are currently working. They all describe the scenario where you use a central git repository, not a central project and that project is connected to a repository. The repository part is not even important we just want to have (at least for now) use it to keep changes. But Since I don't find a single thread on how to do that I guess that is not how you do it :(

Comment: What do you mean by a "central project"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can not see anywhere how to use git the way we are currently working.

What it appears like you want is to have a git checkout on a server, then have multiple developers pushing into that repository and having the working directory update on each push. Git actually prevents you from pushing to a checked out branch to prevent you from smashing any changes currently in the working directory.

There are people out there that do this, though, by not checking out a branch: They setup a git repository on their webserver, add a `post-receive` [git hook](https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) which will `git checkout -f` the most recent commit pushed to a branch. This is the answer to the question you've asked, but is certainly not a recommended setup (though I'm putting it out there because it's at least incrementally better than what you're doing now).

Comment: Hi This is exactly how we have been working for many years.  Was hoping to avoid changing how we work, but I guess the time has come for some changes. Thank you!!, we have some boring administrative work ahead :(